# SetModifiedProperty for nested properties

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, poco

How do you set up SetModifiedProperty for a nested property?, in other words, I have an entity author whose entity have a books collection, I need change just a book name.

```
    var existingAuthor = authors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(authorId));
    var bestSellerBook = existingAuthor.Books.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id.Equals(bookId));
    existingAuthor.Name = "xxxxxxx";
    bestSellerBook.Name = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    context.Authors.Attach(existingAuthor);  
    context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(existingAuthor).SetModifiedProperty("Name");
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You seem to be modifying a book, so why not mark the book as modified the same way you did with the author? Am I misunderstanding your question?

Answer (score 0):

You must get object state entry for the entity holding the property which has changed = in your case it must be the book:

```
var existingAuthor = authors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(authorId));
var bestSellerBook = existingAuthor.Books.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Id.Equals(bookId));
bestSellerBook.Name = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
context.Authors.Attach(existingAuthor);  
context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(bestSellerBook).SetModifiedProperty("Name");
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm modifying 2 entities at the same time (Author & Book).

Comment: @JAPT88 So? You know how to mark the author as modified, and you know how to mark the book as modified. To mark both as modified, first mark one, then mark the other.

Comment: Exactly as @hvd described - if you are modifying multiple entities or properties (with per property granularity) you must set state for each of them.

Comment: Thanks for reply... 
Yes I know, but the problem is: If I mark the two entities as modified, the update sentences will generate an updated including each field and I don't need that, I only need modify the requested ones.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka The problem is I have a complex object graph loaded and only one property of a child is modified. The way I have been doing it so far, setting the state as you say, generates an update for all properties in the object graph.

Comment: @JAPT88 That's not supposed to happen. Please edit your question to include exactly what you've tried, and also please show what the generated SQL looks like.

Comment: No. It must be problem somewhere in your code. I have just made the simplest test to ensure that there isn't any bug and it works exactly as I described.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I should clarify that I am working in a disconnected state. Probably should have mentioned that before, sorry. I think this is probably why I am having these issues.

Comment: Using this scenario only make sense in disconnected state - I did my test with fully disconnected (never loaded) entities.

Comment: Thanks for your help...

I had been looking into msdn and this is what I found:

> When you change the EntityState of an entity object entry to Modified, all the properties of the object are marked as modified, regardless of the current or original values.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.changeobjectstate.aspx